# script broke after upgrading to powershell 3

Tags: powershell, wmi

I have been working on expanding the powershell script from here:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-LocalGroupMembership-87d10dd8

I added the following at the bottom to have it loop through machines in a text file and call the function.

```
$machines = get-content -LiteralPath C:\scripts\hosts.txt
foreach ($ComputerName in $machines) {
get-localgroupmembership -ComputerName $ComputerName
}
```

It was working fine, but then I upgraded to Powershell 3 so that I could use the -append flag for export-csv. Now it is broke.

I keep getting an error when calling `Invoke` at `$members = @($group.psbase.Invoke("Members"))` saying that `The network path was not found`. However, commenting out the for loop at the bottom and manually specifying a single computer allows the script to execute properly. Adding the for loop back in and adding a line to print out the value of `$ComputerName` before calling the `Invoke` line above causes it to properly print each machine name from `hosts.txt` properly before each error.

All machines in hosts.txt are pingable and work just fine when manually specified in the function call instead of using the foreach loop.

Any ideas why this keeps dying on me or how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question, but did you identify to which line it objects and verify the spelling and perhaps try an alternative specification?

Comment: The error references the line I quoted above. Spelling is correct. As I mentioned, it worked perfectly fine (with exception of the desired appending). Then the only thing changed was to upgrade to PS 3.0. After that it no longer worked. Also, manually specifying a single machine instead of looping through the text file still works properly. Alternative specification such as? I'm completely new to powershell.

Comment: I mean, did you have powershell parrot back to you what it thinks the network path is.  Since you updated the language and supporting systems, it's plausible that it *might* be interpreting your input differently than before and differently than what you assume.

Comment: Sorry. I though I covered that. Yes, I had it print out the variable from within the function before making the offending call to verify that it is properly reading each machine name from the text file. I have also manually specified a single machine at a time and it runs just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. The problem was that I needed to set my function to global. The explanation at [this stackexchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070633/powershell-script-module-variables-not-available-outside-of-ise) explained the behavior I was seeing with it working in ISE but not CLI.

Instead of changing any variables as mentioned in that question, I simply changed `function Get-LocalGroupMembership {`

to

`function global:Get-LocalGroupMembership {`

Working like a charm now. Thanks for all the help working through it though.

Answer (score 2):

Just to test.

Try running the script under PowerShell V2.0 using the following:

PS> PowerShell -Version 2.0

When the prompt changes then try again.  See if it works.

I got PowerShell 3.0 loaded the is working fine.  Here's the script:

```
$machines = get-content -LiteralPath C:\temp\hosts.txt;

foreach ($ComputerName in $machines) {
    Get-LocalGroupMembership -ComputerName $ComputerName  `
    | Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\testadmin.csv -NoClobber `
          -NoTypeInformation -Append;
};
```

Comment: I have almost the exact same thing. I tried with and without the ;. At this point, I am just trying to get the script running and output to screen again so I don't have any of the export-csv portion anymore for now. Other than that, my script looks exactly the same and still failing in manually specified PS 1, 2, & 3.

Comment: Now this is strange. The script runs just fine when I run it from within the ISE. However calling it from cmd or PS fails miserably.

Comment: I got it working. The problem was that I needed to set my function to global. The explanation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070633/powershell-script-module-variables-not-available-outside-of-ise explained the behavior I was seeing with it working in ISE but not CLI. Instead of changing any variables, I simply changed "function Get-LocalGroupMembership" to "function global:Get-LocalGroupMembership". Working like a charm now. Since the issue ended up being something completely different, how do I say thanks and give props to y'all without marking an irrelevant answer as correct? Thanks